# Array filter php multi dimensional array

Tags: php

Is there a built in array method in php to filter a nested associative array?

As an example:

```
$myArray = array(
    array('key1' => ''),
    array('key1' => 'value 1'),
    array('key1' => 'value 2'),
);
```

I want to remove any with and empty value - in this example the first element.

I know array_filter would do something similar with a flat array but cant find anything apart from looping over and creating my own new array.  If that is the best solution then thats ok, i can do that myself.  I just didnt want to possibly overlook a built in method for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myArray = array_filter($myArray, function($el){ return !empty($el['key1']); });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are native PHP functions you can use to do this, which is a bit simpler:

1. remove all the keys from nested arrays that contain no value, then
2. remove all the empty nested arrays.

   ```
   $postArr = array_map('array_filter', $postArr);
   $postArr = array_filter( $postArr );
   ```